# Dynamic Data List: Configuring custom datasource for Select Data Definition

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamic-data-list

It is possible to specify or configure a custom datasource to load the select-options for a particular Data definition for Dynamic Data list?

The following image might clarify what I need to do:
[image: Dynamic Data List Data definition screen]

Will it be possible that when the Dynamic Data form is shown to the User the values come from any of the liferay tables like User_, Group_ etc or from any custom plugin portlet's DB table etc.

Thanks

P.S.: Also posted on liferay forum: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/50483965